# How to set record in MySQL into column in datagridview?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to convert records in the database (MySQL) to DataGridView's Header in Visual Studio 2010.

I want to set my datagridview like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTnjb.jpg

This is my script:

```
Private Sub show_data()
        conn.Open()
        Dim strDateTime = Today.Month
        Dim cmdselect = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM sell WHERE month(date)='"& strDateTime &"'", conn)
        Dim rd = cmdselect.ExecuteReader

        If rd.HasRows Then
            Try
                conn.Close()
                conn.Open()

                da = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM sell WHERE month(date)='" & strDateTime & "'", conn)

                'the code maybe goes here..
                (.....)

                dt.Clear()
                da.Fill(dt)
                DGV.DataSource = dt
                Me.DGV.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells)
                conn.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        Else
            MsgBox("Failed")
        End If

        DGV.ReadOnly = True

    End Sub
```

Thank you so much for your helping.
(sorry for my bad English).

Comment: When rows become columns in a query it is called a pivot.  Do a bit of research on that and see what you can come up with for yourself.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. Could you please give me a link that relates to this problem?

Comment: please help me ..

Answer (score 0):

There's no explanation what's "26" and "27" column.

Other then that, one way to do it is:

```
SELECT Description, Total26, Total27 FROM Sell

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Total' as Description, SUM(Total26) as Total26, SUM(Total27) as Total27 FROM Sell
```

Note, that whatever columns you wamt in the result set, the columns in the first half of the `UNION` must match the columns in the second part. That is why I

You want also to visually present the `Total` row, i.e.:

```
Me.DataGridView1.Rows(Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count-1).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Navy;
Me.DataGridView1.Rows(Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count-1).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
  SELECT TOP 5 CAST(BinDateTime as nvarchar(10)) as TestPeriod, Duration FROM Test_BinItems 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TOTAL' as TestPeriod, SUM(Duration) FROM Test_BinItems
```

[image: UNION example]

Note, that this example is using sql server's `TOP 5` to limit result set to 5+1 rows (in MySQL it's a bit different, appending `LIMIT 5`) for clarity. This is not wanted in real scenario.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. 26 and 27 are the date from the sell table. But i need the complete code please..

Comment: You have to provide appropriate information. That is table schema and more. I can only guess what do you mean. I'll modify my answer, hopefully it will help.